# Using a list as a data source for DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, icollection, ordereddictionary

I've extracted the setting names and their respective values out of a configuration file into an ordered dictionary. The dictionary contains keys and values which are of the ICollection class. I want to bind that data and display it in a DataGridView. I've tried copying the strings to arrays and displaying those arrays, but when I ran the program the columns were blank and it did not seem to be binded at all.

I've also attempted to set the DataGridView source directly to one the ordered dictionary collections (keys or values), but that also did not result in anything I wanted; the columns were still blank. However, a third column is made with the column name as "length" and displays the lengths of the entries in the ICollection. But needless to say I do not want the lengths, I want the entries themselves.

Here is the code that I am using for this question: Upon the loading of the form, I load the configuration file and a private member called m_Settings has all the key-value pairs. Then I create a list and add the keys and the values separately. After setting the binding source to 'data', I run the program and both columns I added are both blank.

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadconfigfile(Properties.Settings.Default.Config);
        List<Object> data = new List<Object>();
        data.Add(m_Settings.Keys);
        data.Add(m_Settings.Values);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Any ideas as to how I could get the ordered dictionary and display the entries in two columns labelled "Settings" and "Values"? I believe that lists were compatible DataSources for DataGridViews, but now I'm starting to second-guess myself.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated! I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Here is the revised code with the implemented myStruct class:

```
    List<myStruct> list = new List<myStruct>();
    for(int index = 0; index < m_Settings.Count; index++)
    {
        myStruct pair = new myStruct(keys[index], values[index].ToString());
        list.Add(pair);
    }

    public class myStruct
    {
        private string Key { get; set; }
        private string Value { get; set; }

        public myStruct(string key, string value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

However, when I set the binding DataDource to list, nothing appears on the DataGridView, it's simply empty. Anyone know why?

Comment: Does the above code actually work for you? I tried it out but it didn't work until I changed the `Key` and `Value` to `public` (like they are in the accepted answer...)

Comment: @obe It didn't at the time, it was code based off a suggestion in the answers I got. The answer is the one that actually works.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

First, I don't understand why you are adding all the keys and values count times, Index is never used.

I tried this example :

```
        var source = new BindingSource();
        List<MyStruct> list = new List<MyStruct> { new MyStruct("fff", "b"),  new MyStruct("c","d") };
        source.DataSource = list;
        grid.DataSource = source;
```

and that work pretty well, I get two columns with the correct names. MyStruct type exposes properties that the binding mechanism can use.

```
    class MyStruct
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }


    public MyStruct(string name, string adress)
    {
        Name = name;
        Adres = adress;
    }
  }
```

Try to build a type that takes one key and value, and add it one by one.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @MBen: Ah yes I noticed that just after I posted, my apologies. Thank you for your input, I'll implement something similar and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @MBen: Hello again! I've implemented something along the same lines, like you suggested, please take a look at the edit. The datagridview is unfortunately still empty however. Did I miss something?

Comment: well yes, you should pass as pair-value.
What you are doing is adding the keys, then adding the values, how does it know that you want to have a Key column, value column.
In my example I wrapped string with a Class, and declared public properties. In my example you can replace string name, by KeyType key, and string adress with ValueType. And you need to loop through all you keys and values, and add the new structure one by one.

Comment: @MBen, so as I understand it I should implement a class called KeyType and another called ValueType which contain their respective public properties, then loop through all the keys and values, adding the myStruct structure (which contains KeyType key, ValueType value) one by one.

Comment: No you should create one type that has two properties, one exposing the Key and one exposing the Value.
Class KeyValueClass 
{ public KeyType Key {get;set;}
  public YourValuetype Value {get;set;}
}
then add this  Class to the list one by one.

Comment: @MBen: Got it! It's now fully working. thanks so much for your help and guidance. Have a great day! =)

Answer (score 8):

Set the DataGridView property

```
    gridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

And make sure the list of objects your are binding, those object properties should be public.

Answer (score 3):

this Func may help you . it add every list object to grid view

```
private void show_data()
        {
            BindingSource Source = new BindingSource();

            for (int i = 0; i < CC.Contects.Count; i++)
            {
                Source.Add(CC.Contects.ElementAt(i));
            };


            Data_View.DataSource = Source;

        }
```

I write this for simple database app