# Populating DataGridView with custom DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` with custom `DataGridViewTextIconColumn` (based on `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`) that includes text and small icon.
And I have collection of objects:

```
List<MyClass> data = GetData();
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Image Icon { get; set; }
}
```

And for populating the `DataGridView` I use:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvTest.Rows)
{
    r.Cells[0].Value = "test";
    (r.Cells[0] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell).Icon = testImage;
}
```

But I feel that I do something wrong and should exist a more appropriate way to do it.
How can I bound my `List<MyClass>` to my `DataGridView` with custom `DataGridViewTextIconColumn` which should represents `Name` and `Icon` properties in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you google this, you will come up with many hits on a working solution.

[Using a list as a data source for DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview)

http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/y0wfd4yz(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Standard binding is not work for me. Because I need to display two data values (Name and Icon) in one Cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to watch out.

- The regular way to use `Databinding` is to set the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` to a **proper** DataSource. This can be a `List<MyClass>` but `MyClass` must expose its values as `Properties`!

So the class should probably be changed to

```
List<MyClass> data = GetData();
class MyClass
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Image icon {get;set;}
}
```

Now you could already display the data with regular `DataBinding` except that your `Image` will not be displayed in an automatically generated TextCell. So you could swtich to generating the Columns in code like this:

```
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name", "Name");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn(false));

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "name";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "icon";
```

and this will display the data:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

- However you have a special custom `Column` and it seems as if you want it to display two data values (name and icon) in one `Cell`. I have doubts that this is possible with out-of-the-box DataBinding.

But maybe I'm wrong and we can find a way, if you show us the definition for you custom column..