# Passing data from textbox to datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I am working in Visual Studio running a Windows application.

I am wondering if I can fill a `DataGridView` from a `TextBox`, that was a passed value itself?

For example, the user would search for a patient from a dialog form. The patient's name they select would populate a `TextBox` on my main form. I want that selected patients prior test history to populate a `DataGridView` on that main form within a tab.

Is this possible, if so how would I accomplish this?

Comment: What you will need to do is to get the prior test history either using the text in the `TextBox` or by using the patient selected in your dialog form and once you have the history loading it in the `DataGridView`. If the history is a list check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I would suggest setting up some sort of data binding. More specifically you will want some class that maintains state and data binds to your controls and possibly your dialog form. I don't know how much you are looking for so this might be going overboard but I would suggest something like this:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm(StateManager stateManager)
    {
        _stateManager = stateManager;

        //data binding for your text box
        txtPatientName.DataBindings.Add(nameof(txtPatientName.Text), stateManager, nameof(stateManager.PatientName));

        //data binding for your grid
        historyGrid.DataSource = stateManager.History;
    }

    private void btnShowForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var form = new DialogForm())
        {
            var result = form.ShowDialog();
            if(result == DialogResult.Ok)
            {
                _stateManager.UpdatePatient(form.InputPatientName);
            }
        }
    }

    private StateManager _stateManager;
}

//this is the form where you enter the patient name
public class DialogForm : Form
{
    //this holds the value where the patient's name is entered on the form
    public string InputPatientName { get; set; }
}

//this class maintains your state
public class StateManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string PatientName
    {
        get { return _patientName; }
        set 
        {
            _patientName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PatientName));
        }
    }

    public BindingList<MedicalHistoryItems> History => _history ?? (_history = new BindingList<MedicalHistoryItems>());

    public void UpdatePatient(string patientName)
    {
        History.Clear();

        var historyRetriever = new HistoryRetriever();
        History.AddRange(historyRetriever.RetrieveHistory(patientName));
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(propertyName);
    }

    private BindingList<MedicalHistoryItems> _history;
    private string _patientName;
}
```