# How to connect a class list in another class to the DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

> Class Student

```
class StudentInfo
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public String FullName { get; set; }
        public String LessonStudy { get; set; }
        public String GroupName { get; set; }
        public StatusStudentBell StatusStudentBell { get; set; }
    }
```

> class StatusStudentBell

```
class StatusStudentBell
    {
        public String Bell1 { get; set; }
        public String Bell2 { get; set; }
        public String Bell3 { get; set; }
        public String Bell4 { get; set; }
    }
```

> In Form

```
ConservatoryEntities ConservatoryEntities = new ConservatoryEntities();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var student = ConservatoryEntities.LocationTimeClasses.Where(l =>
                    l.Day.Name.Equals("Friday"));

            var dateNow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString());

            var studentInfo = new List<StudentInfo>();
            foreach (var item in student)
            {

                studentInfo.AddRange(item.LessonToFieldStudy.FieldOfStudy.Students.ToList().Select(s => 
                new StudentInfo()
                {
                    FullName = s.Name,
                    GroupName = s.Team.Name,
                    LessonStudy = s.FieldOfStudy.Name,
                    StatusStudentBell = new StatusStudentBell()
                    {
                        Bell1 = item.LessonToFieldStudy.RollCalls.FirstOrDefault(r => r.fk_bell_Id == 1 && 
                        r.Date == dateNow)?.Absent + "",
                        Bell2 = item.LessonToFieldStudy.RollCalls.FirstOrDefault(r => r.fk_bell_Id == 2 && 
                        r.Date == dateNow)?.Absent + "",
                    }
                }).ToList());


            }

        }
```

I'm just using C # and I am a beginner.

In C #, I want to connect this list that I've created to a dataGridView.

How can I add the `StudentInfo` list in which the `StatusStudentBell` class can connect to a DataGridView?

Please Help me.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview Also try to research a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LessonStudy", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("GroupName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bell1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bell2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bell3", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Bell4", typeof(string));

            List<StudentInfo> studentInfo = new List<StudentInfo>() {
               new StudentInfo() { FullName = "John", GroupName = "Apple", LessonStudy = "Math", StudentId = 123, StatusStudentBell = new StatusStudentBell() { Bell1 = "A", Bell2 = "B", Bell3 = "C", Bell4 = "D"}},
               new StudentInfo() { FullName = "Marry", GroupName = "Bannana", LessonStudy = "English", StudentId = 345, StatusStudentBell = new StatusStudentBell() { Bell1 = "E", Bell2 = "F", Bell3 = "G", Bell4 = "H"}},
               new StudentInfo() { FullName = "Harry", GroupName = "Grape", LessonStudy = "French", StudentId = 678, StatusStudentBell = new StatusStudentBell() { Bell1 = "I", Bell2 = "J", Bell3 = "K", Bell4 = "L"}},
               new StudentInfo() { FullName = "July", GroupName = "Pinapple", LessonStudy = "Gym", StudentId = 246, StatusStudentBell = new StatusStudentBell() { Bell1 = "M", Bell2 = "N", Bell3 = "O", Bell4 = "P"}}
            };

            foreach (StudentInfo info in studentInfo)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { info.FullName, info.GroupName, info.LessonStudy, info.StudentId, info.StatusStudentBell.Bell1, info.StatusStudentBell.Bell2, info.StatusStudentBell.Bell3, info.StatusStudentBell.Bell4 });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        class StudentInfo
        {
            public int StudentId { get; set; }
            public String FullName { get; set; }
            public String LessonStudy { get; set; }
            public String GroupName { get; set; }
            public StatusStudentBell StatusStudentBell { get; set; }
        }
        class StatusStudentBell
        {
            public String Bell1 { get; set; }
            public String Bell2 { get; set; }
            public String Bell3 { get; set; }
            public String Bell4 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```