# Fill ComboBox in Datagridview from Enums

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums

this is my enum class:

```
   public enum Uom
        {
            not_known,
            lbs,
            psi,
            tank,
            tube,
            each,
            gallon,
            meters,
            cc,
            mg,
            bag,
            capsule
    }
```

and i want to populate combobox in my second column in datagridview1. i tried this code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtgcombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

dtgcombo.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Uom));

datagridview1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0", dtgcombo});
```

but it error says "...value is not valid"

Comment: Have you checked *[this...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx)* ?

Comment: i dont get it sorry :(

Comment: Which line produces this error? Also try the answer added by @Engineer to add columns and refer this answer on this linked example for setting the data source for list of items. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is trying to add a `DataGridviewColumn` to a `DataGridViewCell.` This will not work as you expect. In addition, it makes no sense to add the same combo box to every cell in the column. You should add the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to the `DataGridView` as Engineer answered. Then, when you add a row and you know what `enum` to use… then you would add the row like: `datagridview1.Rows.Add("0", Uom.tank.ToString());` The second parameter could be any of the enums. The code below should accomplish what you are trying to do. The second column is the combo box column.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dtgcombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
dtgcombo.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Uom));
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dtgcombo);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("0", Uom.meters.ToString());
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("0", "");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("0", Uom.not_known.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
datagridview1.Columns.Add(dtgcombo);
```

adds the combobox as a column for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer i got so far.. forgot the link of my reference

```
var dtgcombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
dtgcombo.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Uom)); 

int n = dtgRequests.Rows.Add();
    datagridview1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = "0";
    datagridview1.Rows[n].Cells[1] = dtgcombo;
```

thanks a lot guys for the help !