# c# Break down Class Method's String to Form's DataGridView Table

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble to transfer **Information from Class' Method to Form's DataGridView**.

My class has the following code:

```
public virtual void position(string account, Contract contract, double pos, double avgCost)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Position. " + account + " - Symbol: " + contract.Symbol + ", SecType: " + contract.SecType + ", Currency: " + contract.Currency + ", Position: " + pos + ", Avg cost: " + avgCost);
            string text = account + "|" + contract.Symbol + "|" + contract.SecType + "|" + contract.Currency + "|" + pos + "|" + avgCost;
            myform.AddItemToDataGridView(text);
        }
```

And my Form has:

```
    public void AddItemToDataGridView(string text)
    {
        // See if a new invocation is required form a different thread
        if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback h = new SetTextCallback(AddItemToDataGridView);
            this.Invoke(h, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Account";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Symbol";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Security Type";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Currency";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Position";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Average Cost";

            // What should i add here to break down my string into the right columns?

        }
    }
```

> Can someone help me to break down that string in to right columns?
>   There should be much better ways to do this. However, I cant get them to work

Comment: `text.Split('|')` sould give you a string array. In `AddItemToDataGridView` you should add a new row for the DataGrid and populate with the results of the array, but I can't help you if I don't know what are you using for your UI. Ist it Windows Forms, WPF or something else?

Comment: Window Form. Ill try it

Comment: If is windows forms this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically) will be helpful.

Comment: string[] row1 = text.Split('|');
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);

Comment: how about to encapsulate string values in class and pass it to gridView datasource ?    no need to set columns name multiple times , one time is enough

Comment: That sounds super cool, could you give an example on how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview