# Sort the output according to variable "nivå", every time the button "lägg_till" is pressed

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp58
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        List<Säljare> säljare = new List<Säljare>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        class Säljare
        {

            private string namn;
            private double personnr;
            private string distrikt;
            private int antal;
            private int nivå;

            public Säljare(string namn, double personnr, string distrikt, int antal, int nivå)
            {

                this.namn = namn;
                this.personnr = personnr;
                this.distrikt = distrikt;
                this.antal = antal;
                this.Nivå = nivå;

            }
            public string Namn
            {
                get { return namn; }
                set { namn = value; }
            }
            public double Personnr
            {
                get { return personnr; }
                set { personnr = value; }
            }
            public string Distrikt
            {
                get { return distrikt; }
                set { distrikt = value; }
            }
            public int Antal
            {
                get { return antal; }
                set { antal = value; }
            }
            public int Nivå
            {
                get { return nivå; }
                set { nivå = value; }
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return namn + ": " + personnr + " " + distrikt + " " + antal;
            }
```

/*I want the output here (when clicked) to be sorted according to
variable nivå(which is 1, 2, 3 or 4),
so that each line that has nivå = 1 is stacked above those with nivå=2 and so on
*/

```
            private void btn_läggtill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string namn = txtn.Text;
                double personnr;
                if (!double.TryParse(txtp.Text, out personnr))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("personnummer måste vara ett tal"); return;

                }

                string distrikt = txtd.Text;


                int antal = 0;
                if (!int.TryParse(txta.Text, out antal))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Antal måste vara ett tal"); return;

                }

                int nivå = 0;

                if (antal < 50) { nivå = 1; }
                if (antal > 50 || antal < 100) { nivå = 2; }
                if (antal >= 100 || antal <= 199) { nivå = 3; }
                if (antal > 199) { nivå = 4; }





                Säljare nySäljare = new Säljare(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);

                säljare.Add(nySäljare);
                dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Add(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);
                dgvViewsäljare.Rows[dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Count - 1].Tag = nySäljare;


            }

            private void btn_spara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DialogResult resultat = dlgSparaSom.ShowDialog();

                if (resultat == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    FileStream utStröm = new FileStream(dlgSparaSom.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                    BinaryWriter skrivare = new BinaryWriter(utStröm);

                    int antalsäljare = säljare.Count;
                    skrivare.Write(antalsäljare);

                    for (int i = 0; i < säljare.Count; i++)
                    {

                        skrivare.Write(säljare[i].Namn);
                        skrivare.Write(säljare[i].Personnr);
                        skrivare.Write(säljare[i].Distrikt);
                        skrivare.Write(säljare[i].Antal);


                    }
                    skrivare.Dispose();

                }
            }

            private void btn_öppna_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DialogResult resultat = dlgÖppnaFil.ShowDialog();

                if (resultat == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Clear();

                    FileStream inStröm = new FileStream(dlgÖppnaFil.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    BinaryReader läsare = new BinaryReader(inStröm);

                    int antalsäljare = läsare.ReadInt32();

                    for (int i = 0; i < antalsäljare; i++)
                    {
                        string namn = läsare.ReadString();
                        double personnr = läsare.ReadSingle();
                        string distrikt = läsare.ReadString();
                        int antal = (int)läsare.ReadSingle();
                        int nivå = (int)läsare.ReadSingle();

                        Säljare nysäljare = new Säljare(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);
                        säljare.Add(nysäljare);

                        dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Add(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal);
                        dgvViewsäljare.Rows[dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Count - 1].Tag = nysäljare;


                    }
                    läsare.Dispose();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//This is a program that registers a new user(säljare) every time the button "lägg_till" is clicked, this works, except for the fact that its not sorted according to variable "nivå"

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
// according to variable nivå(which is 1, 2, 3 or 4),
// so that each line that has nivå = 1 is stacked above those with nivå=2 and so on 
säljare = säljare
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Nivå == 1)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Nivå == 2)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Nivå == 3)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Nivå == 4)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Nivå) // all others, if possible
    .ToList();
```

That's a conditional sort order. I use `Descending` since the comparison returns a `bool` and `true` is "higher" than `false`.

Maybe you can simplify it to(if no other values are possible):

```
int[] nivåOrder = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
säljare = säljare.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(nivåOrder, x.Nivå)).ToList();
```

**Edit**: If the logic is that simple you can even use:

```
säljare = säljare.OrderBy(x => x.Nivå).ToList();
```

or even without LINQ and without creating a new list:

```
säljare.Sort((x, y) => x.Nivå.CompareTo(y.Nivå));
```

Comment: How do I output this new sorted list into a datagridview? (like im trying in my code).

Comment: @LOTUS: so you don't know how to use your list as source for a `DataGridView`? This is covered in other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473326/using-a-list-as-a-data-source-for-datagridview